# Python .sort() command works as pointer?

Tags: list, python-2.7, sorting

i encountered a weird thing about the .sort() command in python 2.7.

to explain i'll use a simple code -

```
A = [1,3,2]
B = A
B.sort()

print A
```

in this code i create a non sorted list A, i then copy that list into B, sort B and print A.
for some reason when i print A i get a sorted list [1,2,3] even though i used the sort command on B.

on the other hand if i'll write the following code -

```
A = [1,3,2]
B = A
B[1] = 123

print A
```

it'll print A as it should - [1,3,2]

if someone can suggest an explanation it'll be great
thanks

Comment: You didn't make a copy; you only created an additional reference to the same object. This has little to do with sorting; `list.sort()` sorts the list in-place so all references to the list will see the changes made.

Comment: Your second example prints `[1, 123, 2]`, as it should. It'll never print `[1, 3, 2]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `sort()`.

```
B = A
```

Now B and A are two different names for, or references to, the same list object.

You can confirm this by calling `id()` and seeing that it reutns the same value for both names.

If you want a **copy** of the list, do:

```
B = list(A)
```

Comment: does the same apply to any variable or only lists?

Comment: @IdoGD: it applies to any mutable object that you alter. Numbers and strings are not mutable, so you end up *rebinding* the name. `a = 5`. `a = a + 5` assigns a new object to `a`, the `int` instance is never itself altered.

Comment: got it, thanks alot!